# Page-level css to go with a themeroller theme?

Tags: jquery-ui-theme

Having selected a theme from themeroller, I'd now like to put together some compatible CSS for the rest of the page that includes the jquery components that respect the theme. Is there any shortcut for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the hex values and fonts that you used in your Theme to build your own custom css file.  You can gather all of these values using the Edit feature on the ThemeRoller page for the theme that you've selected.